# Replace with probability of occuring

Tags: python

I recently asked a question regarding randomly replacing with a set frequency. However, I am also interested in replacing within a single column. However, what I am finding is that with my current code, the probability of a value being replaced is roughly 50%. However, I want to be able to change the probability of a value being replaced to something like 1% or 5%. So for example, I would like the value to be replaced only 1% of the time. I am just not sure how to do this. I read a couple of posts that typed about being able to do this with `numpy`, however, I am not working with a numpy array

```
import random
vals = ['*','1','0']
with open("test2.txt","w") as out, open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            li=line.strip()
            tabs = li.split("\t")
            geno = tabs[2]
            print(geno)
            for index, x in enumerate(geno):
                if random.randint(0, 1):
                    geno = random.choice(vals)
            print(geno)
```

a few example lists

```
[1]
[0]
[-]
```

an example of the actual dataset

```
AAD 1 0
ADE - 0
ARD 1 1
GRE 0 0
```

Comment: Do you need something more complicated than `if random.random() < 0.01:`?

Comment: No, that would actually work out perfectly

Comment: Well I guess something like `if random.random() <= 0.01:` might be better

Comment: No, actually, it wouldn't.  Saying `<= 0.01` gets you fractionally MORE than 1%.

Comment: @TimRoberts that is very true. If you want to convert that into an answer, I will accept it. I didn't think it was going to be so simple...

Comment: Aren't you replacing an iterable with a single value? I'm confused why `geno = random.choice(vals)` isn't `geno[index] = random.choice(vals)`. (And if that is what you intended to do, you could use a list comprehension instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `random.choice(vals+[x], weights = [1,1,1,99*len(vals)])`. If `x` is in `vals`, the probability of ending up with `x` will be a bit more than 99%, since it can be replaced by itself. This issue is true of Tim Roberts' answer as well. You might also want to define a parameter for the weight, so you don't have a "magic number" in the random choice line:

```
replacement_prob = .01
random.choice(vals+[x], weights = [replacement_prob]*len(vals)+[(1-replacement_prob)*len(vals)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is as simple as

```
        if random.random() < 0.01:
```